# cannot be cast to android.widget.AdapterView$OnItemSelectedListener

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, android-asynctask

I have encountered the following unexpected issues when trying to run my application.
Essentially I am creating a scheduling system, where a user select the calendar date, and select the time of the day from a spinner drop down option (morning, afternoon, evening), and these information gets displayed in their respected textview. I have encountered the following error while trying to do so:

```
cannot be cast to android.widget.AdapterView$OnItemSelectedListener
```

Also for some reason, my spinner is not being displayed in the application, when it is visible in the eclipse layout preview, so I wonder if its visibility is directly related to the error of this code.

Below is the logcat message:

```
09-18 02:27:36.881: E/AndroidRuntime(5871): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-18 02:27:36.881: E/AndroidRuntime(5871): Process: com.dooba.beta, PID: 5871
09-18 02:27:36.881: E/AndroidRuntime(5871): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.dooba.beta.ScheduleMatchOptionActivity cannot be cast to android.widget.AdapterView$OnItemSelectedListener
09-18 02:27:36.881: E/AndroidRuntime(5871):     at com.dooba.beta.ScheduleMatchOptionActivity.onClick(ScheduleMatchOptionActivity.java:132)
09-18 02:27:36.881: E/AndroidRuntime(5871):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
09-18 02:27:36.881: E/AndroidRuntime(5871):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
09-18 02:27:36.881: E/AndroidRuntime(5871):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
09-18 02:27:36.881: E/AndroidRuntime(5871):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
09-18 02:27:36.881: E/AndroidRuntime(5871):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-18 02:27:36.881: E/AndroidRuntime(5871):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
09-18 02:27:36.881: E/AndroidRuntime(5871):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-18 02:27:36.881: E/AndroidRuntime(5871):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-18 02:27:36.881: E/AndroidRuntime(5871):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
09-18 02:27:36.881: E/AndroidRuntime(5871):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
09-18 02:27:36.881: E/AndroidRuntime(5871):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Below is the activity code:

```
public class ScheduleMatchOptionActivity extends Activity implements
OnClickListener {

// Widget GUI
protected TextView mCalendarDate;
protected TextView mCalendarTime;
Button btnCalendar, btnTimePicker;
TextView txtDate, txtTime;

// Variable for storing current date and time
private int mYear, mMonth, mDay, mHour, mMinute;

private Spinner spinner;
private static final String[]paths = {"Morning", "Afternoon", "Evening"};

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.match_schedule);
txtDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
txtTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTime);


Button mConfirm2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnConfirmSchedule);
        mConfirm2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

             // Create the class and the columns
                currentUser.saveInBackground();

                currentUser.put("ActivityDate", txtDate.getText().toString()); 
                currentUser.put("ActivityTime", txtTime.getText().toString());
                currentUser.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

                        if (e == null) {
                            // Success!
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ScheduleMatchOptionActivity.this, PayPalPaymentActivity.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent); 
                        }
                        else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ScheduleMatchOptionActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage(e.getMessage())
                                .setTitle(R.string.signup_error_title)
                                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                            dialog.show();
                        }
                 }
             });
            }
        });

btnCalendar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCalendar);

txtDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
txtTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTime);

btnCalendar.setOnClickListener(this);
btnTimePicker.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

if (v == btnCalendar) {

    // Process to get Current Date
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // Launch Date Picker Dialog
    DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this,
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                        int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    // Display Selected date in textbox
                    txtDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "-"
                            + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);

                }
            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    dpd.show();
}


spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinTime);
ArrayAdapter<String>adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ScheduleMatchOptionActivity.this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,paths);

adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener((OnItemSelectedListener) this);

}

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

switch (position) {
    case 0:
        txtTime.setText("Morning");
        break;
    case 1:
        txtTime.setText("Afternoon");

        break;
    case 2:
        txtTime.setText("E");

        break;

}
}

}
```

Below is the layout portion:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

</TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tAge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnCalendar"
        android:paddingBottom="25dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="Date and Time Picker Dialog"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="20sp" >

</TextView>
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTime"
        android:layout_width="155dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/spinTime"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Select your time"
        android:textColor="#C11B17"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnCalendar"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tAge" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtDate"
            android:layout_width="155dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Select your date"
            android:textColor="#C11B17"
            android:textSize="18sp" >

            <requestFocus />
        </TextView>

    </RelativeLayout>



    <Spinner
      android:id="@+id/spinTime"
      android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#D1D0CE"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnCalendar"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnCalendar"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCalendar"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#D1D0CE"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtTime"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:text="Calendar" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnConfirmSchedule"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtTime"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:background="#C11B17"
        android:text="Confirm"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

If you need further clarification, let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class must implement `OnItemSelectedListener`

```
public class ScheduleMatchOptionActivity extends Activity implements 
OnClickListener, OnItemSelectedListener
```